# What are good polling algorithms

Tags: algorithm, twitter, sensors, polling

I am trying to create an application for polling different sensors. I want to make this polling efficient so that I don't poll a slow changing sensor very frequently. On the other hand there may be some sensors like temp sensor whose values keep on changing frequently.

I found an analogy in twitter. When a twitter stream is open how does it automatically give real time notifications of new tweets? . They must be polling a web server of tweet. Right? How this polling rate is decided. There must be some algorithms or may be I am missing proper term/keyword for this thing to Google it. This must have got something to do with push and pull based architectures. Right?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Also, you may want to accept some answers on your past questions.

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to see the network connections Twitter is making to the server.

Comment: If something really uses a push-based architecture, then it *isn't* polling the server. If these are simple, low-level physical sensors, then maybe they aren't capable of "pushing" updates to your system. Can you actually describe *your* situation, and the problem you're trying to solve? This stuff about twitter might be a complete red herring. Polling rates depend completely on the application - maybe an update every second is close enough to real-time for twitter. What's *your* application?

Comment: There is no such thing as pushing to a web browser unless its a java or flash plugin.  There really is no "Algorithm".  You pick a polling interval (30 seconds, 5 minutes, its up to you).  Depending on what the language supports, you then either have a timer triggering an update function or you have `while loop` which updates then sleeps and repeats this for ever.

Comment: I don't see any connection between polling "different" sensors (which ones?) with Twitter real-time notifications. If your sensors don't report at their own fixed rates and you need to poll them, then it solely depends on the type of the sensor, and this is more likely a problem related to the field of application. You won't be polling car speed sensors the same way you will poll a simple water heating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting accurate sensor waveforms, search for Nyquist rate, e.g., [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)

If you are going to be filtering your sensor streams, it is best to sample at a fixed frequency to make the filter math easier.